# Is PixiJs is good for creating Graph to plot large number of data points with zoom and scroll

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, pixi.js, easeljs

I want to build a Graph with scroll and zoom something similar to this (https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v4/line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom-v4/) with lot more customization. I don't want to use any built in charting libraries, want to build a custom one using canvas. Performance is one main concern because there will be large number of data points in my graph. Is PixiJs is good for this?

Which drawing library is better for my requirement?